# ExpressJS uncaughtException: [TypeError: opt.expires.toUTCString is not a function]

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting the following weird behaviour which happens randomly and I can't reproduce but I can "fix".

I have a static webapp that I send as a file from my express api.
I'm not sure it's best practice but this is what I do on the router:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var webAppDir = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..','webAppSimple');

//show user profile
if(req.isAuthenticated() || CONSTS.WEBAPP.DEBUG == 1) {
    res.sendFile(webAppDir + '/index.html');
    //res.json({});

}
//show signup
else {
    res.redirect('/signup');
} 

});
```

Then I get the following error:

```
'TypeError: opt.expires.toUTCString is not a function',
 '    at Object.serialize (/Users/andreymigalovich/Projects_localMac/print-that-sheet/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/cookie/index.js:135:56)',
 '    at ServerResponse.res.cookie (/Users/andreymigalovich/Projects_localMac/print-that-sheet/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:804:36)',
 '    at ServerResponse.res.writeHead (/Users/andreymigalovich/Projects_localMac/print-that-sheet/server/node_modules/express-session/index.js:168:11)',
 '    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)',
 '    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:433:10)',
 '    at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:529:20)',
 '    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)',
 '    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:182:7)',
 '    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:147:16)',
 '    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)',
 '    at onread (fs.js:1818:12)',
 '    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:614:17)'
```

If I change the res.sendFile(webAppDir + '/index.html'); to res.json({});
I don't get an error and the browser shows an empty page (as it should..)

The problem is "fixed" when I delete the entire content on the index.html page, refresh the browser then paste the content again (without changing anything) and refresh the browser again. Doing this fixes the problem for an unknown amount of time.

I'm using nodejs v5.6.0 with: 
 "express": "~4.13.1" and "express-session": "~1.0.0"

Hoping to get a better understanding of what's going on or even change the way I send static files to avoid this whole issue.

Comment: I think it's something to do with `express-session` and `express` module version compatibility.

Comment: Did you check this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607293/expiration-object-in-express-session-not-the-correct-type

Comment: I don't know how to verify that changing the 'expires' property from a number to a date object fixes my issue but I did it and I hope it's fixed. Thank you @PhagunBaya I missed that question when searching for a solution.